# How to call some code if users press back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

In `UINavigationController`?

For example, say I want to make sure that the `UINavigationController` is not animating when user press the back button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't intending to intercept the back button tap itself but instead the act of the current view controller disappearing, you can use:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        // handle back button press
    }
}
```

If you are sure you want to do the back button, you can create your own custom `UIBarButtonItem` and set it to the current controller's `leftBarButtonItem`.  Be sure to call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` after you have finished doing your own logic.

Comment: Once it shows up on viewWillDisappear, not like I can cancel the process right. I want to cancel the process if things are not completed yet.

Comment: Correct, at this point you can't cancel it.  If that is your goal, I would either add a custom button to implement any logic to ignore touches until you are ready or just disable/remove the system-provided back button (maybe replace it with a Cancel button?).

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in ViewDidLoad of your application :

```
    UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 55.0f, 35.0f)];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

This create a custom Back button. "Back.png" is image same as that of OS.

Add below code as function. This one pops to RootViewcontroller.

```
- (void) backClicked:(id)sender {

// perform certain task
// If task is completed then call below LOC

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

[image]